# SSRS cell formatting

Tags: reporting-services

I have requirement to change the background color of cell based on DB flag.

This are the possible flags:

- `flag="1"` background color of full row should be Green
- `flag=2` background of full row should be RED
- `flag=3` only particular cell should be highlighted with background as Yellow.

Currently I have added expression on every cell to check flag but it is creating performance issue. Is it possible to add/remove cell level expression dynamically?

I will add expression at row level and add/remove cell expression based on flag.

Comment: Do a search on how to color alternating rows.   This is done on a row level and you can easily adapt this to set the full row to a specific color based on the flag.   With regards to the specific cell, set the background color of that specific cell and it will override the row setting.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a **Calculated column** to the dataset which does the check and returns the proper color.

```
=IIF(Fields!flag.Value = 1, "GREEN", 
 IIF(Fields!flag.Value = 2, "RED", 
 IIF(Fields!flag.Value = 3, "YELLOW", "BLACK")
```

Then set the **Background color** to that new field.